# Retomar para última activity mesmo quando o app é forçado a fechar pelo usuário

Tags: android

Tenho uma aplicação similar aos aplicativos de táxi. Acontece que no aplicativo do motorista enquanto ele está se deslocando para buscar o passageiro, caso ele feche o aplicativo forçadamente ou o aparelho reinicie ou dê algum crash, quando abre o app novamente ele retorna para a Tela inicial. 
Eu já implementei o `onSaveInstance()` e funciona perfeitamente para quando o app é morto pelo sistema. Porém eu preciso de uma solução para quando o usuário quer encerrar a app ou quando o aparelho reinicia ele volte para a última `activity` em execução que era a de acompanhamento da corrida.

Comment: Você pode salvar nas sharedPrefferences a última tela do usuário, implemente um método e chame ele sempre no onDestroy(); Caso o usuário feche o app..você pode criar um serviço que force ele a ficar com o app aberto, mas acho isso meio "perigoso".

Comment: @CarlosBridi, acho que chamar o onDestroy não é uma boa idéa... Eu gravaria no onResume, pelo que entendi, por exemplo se o usuário tirar a bateria, não vai conseguir chamar o onDestroy por exemplo..

Comment: @CarlosBridi Eu tentei usar o sharedprefferences, mas quando eu fecho forçadamente o sharedprefferences é limpo e volta para default. Parece algum bug do android até já pesquisei sobre...

Answer (score 0):

Tive que faz algo parecido uma vez...

Criei uma classe que herda de application
e criei, dentro dela estes métodos para ler e gravar a activity atual.

```
public class AppApplication extends Application
{
    private Activity mCurrentActivity = null;
    public Activity getCurrentActivity(){
        return mCurrentActivity;
    }
    public void setCurrentActivity(Activity mCurrentActivity){
        this.mCurrentActivity = mCurrentActivity;
    }
}
```

Criei também uma classe que continha a implementação base das activity's

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity{

    protected AppApplication application;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
        //faz o cast para o tipo da minha classe de Application
        application = (AppApplication)this.getApplicationContext(); 
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        //cada vez que é criada ou é resumida a activity grava a activity atual
        //ou seja sempre vou ter a Activity atual "gravada"
        //você pode fazer guardar ao invés da instância da activity, grava uma TAG que identifica e grava em algum local, e na hora de abrir o app você ler deste local.
        application.setCurrentActivity(this); 
    }
}
```

alterei todas minhas activitys para

```
public class Exemplo extends BaseActivity {
    ...
}
```

e no manifesto adicionar a sua classe AppAplication

```
<application
            android:name=".Globais.AppAplication"
            android:icon=...
            android:label=...
            android:theme=...>
        <activity...
```

sei que não é muito bem o que você precisa, mas decidi compartilhar minha experiência, pois quando não se tem nada.. alguma coisa é muito útil..

Espero ter ajudado!!